# React: What does following mean: import register, * as fromRegister from './registerReducer'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

What does the following mean: `import register, * as fromRegister from './registerReducer'`?

What does the part `register and * as fromRegister` represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It imports `register` because it's default export, and then imports all contents with `*` as `fromRegister`. Let me break it down:

```
import register, * as fromRegister from './registerReducer'
```

It imports the export `register` which is exported by default, into the current scope, with `export default ...` and then imports all contents with `*` as `fromRegister`, which is a label, from the file `registerReducer.js`. You can read more at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults).

Comment: @LyManeug No problem! If you have any more question, I'll be happy to help!

Comment: Just one more question if you don't mind, do you know what the `...` in the following is doing? `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ...getNav(state),
})` Thank you again!

Comment: @LyManeug That's called a spread operator I believe. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). If you still don't understand, I suggest asking another question.

Comment: Got it. One last question to confirm, `{this.props.onLoggin && <Text>Loggin In</Text>}` Does this mean this.props.onLoggin has to be true in order for the `<Text>Loggin In</Text>` to be rendered? Otherwise, the `<Text/>` wouldn't be showing?

Comment: @LyManeug Yes. It means if the left side is true, then do the right side. Think of it as `if left then right`.

Comment: got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`import register` will import `register`, which is the default export. In the body of your script, you can call `register` directly.

When importing like `import * as fromRegister` we are import all named exports (the default export, should on exist, is not named).  Assuming the `registerReducer` module has a named function like `helloWorld()`, you would call it like `fromRegister.helloWorld()`

Note: If you wanted to import some non-default exports (but not the module), you can import it by name (e.g., `import {helloWorld} from 'registerReducer';`)

Answer (score 0):

`register` creates a `register` variable that links to th to the default export, while `* as fromRegister` creates a `fromRegister` object that exposes all named exports as properties.